# JavaScript not working (Custom Dialog Box)

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, .net

Following this tutorial,

[Custom DialogBox](http://aspalliance.com/1366_Building_a_Custom_Confirmation_Dialog_Box.all)

I already have 3 asp content place holder for a ASP.Net page and they are already using some kind script I guess, which isn't problem here.

Problem is, I am able to call a function using "OnClientClick" attribute but this functions have more functions in a different .js file. If i Put alert before it calling other functions it works but not after it goes my first function.

Tutorial got all the javascript code listed, Here's the Code that I am using in my ASP.Net Content place to make it work,

```
<asp:Content ID="Content4" ContentPlaceHolderID="cphSubmit" runat="server">
 <script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/1033/jquery.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript" src="CustomDialog.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
        function ShowMessage()
        {
            alert("1");
            SetText('Yes','No');
            alert("2");
            DisplayConfirmMessage('are you sure',180,90)
            SetDefaultButton('btnConfOK');
            return false;
        }
 </script>
            <div id="divConfMessage" runat="server" style="BORDER-RIGHT:black thin solid; BORDER-TOP:black thin solid; DISPLAY:none; Z-INDEX:200; BORDER-LEFT:black thin solid; BORDER-BOTTOM:black thin solid">
            <div style="BACKGROUND-COLOR: #6699cc;TEXT-ALIGN: center" id="confirmText">
            </div>
            <div style="Z-INDEX: 105;HEIGHT: 2%;BACKGROUND-COLOR: white;TEXT-ALIGN: center">
            </div>
            <div style="Z-INDEX: 105;BACKGROUND-COLOR: white;TEXT-ALIGN: center">
                <asp:Button ID="btnConfOK" Runat="server" Text="OK"></asp:Button>
                <asp:Button ID="btnConfCancel" Runat="server" Text="Cancel"></asp:Button>
            </div>
        </div>
<hr />


    <asp:Button ID="btDelete" runat="server" 
    OnClientClick="ShowMessage();"
    Text="Delete" UseSubmitBehavior="False" Width="200px"  />
```

I removed some other controls I have for the moment, It shows Alert "1" but doesn't reach "2",

here's the 
CustomDialog Script,

```
var divWidth = '';
var divHeight = '';
var txtFirstButton = 'OK';
var txtSecondButton = 'Cancel'
    function DisplayConfirmMessage(msg,width,height)
    {
            // Set default dialogbox width if null
            if(width == null)
            divWidth = 180 
            else 
            divWidth = width;

            // Set default dialogBox height if null
            if(height == null)
            divHeight = 90 
            else 
            divHeight = height;


            // Ge the dialogbox object
            var divLayer = document.getElementById('divConfMessage');
            // Set dialogbox height and width
            SetHeightWidth(divLayer)
            // Set dialogbox top and left
            SetTopLeft(divLayer);

            // Show the div layer
            divLayer.style.display = 'block';
            // Change the location and reset the width and height if window is resized
            window.onresize = function() { if(divLayer.style.display == 'block'){ SetTopLeft(divLayer); SetHeightWidth(divLayer)}}
            // Set the dialogbox display message
            document.getElementById('confirmText').innerText = msg;
    }

    function SetTopLeft(divLayer)
    {
        // Get the dialogbox height
        var divHeightPer = divLayer.style.height.split('px')[0];

         // Set the top variable 
        var top = (parseInt(document.body.offsetHeight)/ 2) - (divHeightPer/2)
        // Get the dialog box width
        var divWidthPix = divLayer.style.width.split('px')[0];

        // Get the left variable
        var left = (parseInt(document.body.offsetWidth)/2) - (parseInt(divWidthPix)/2);
        // set the dialogbox position to abosulute
        divLayer.style.position = 'absolute';

        // Set the div top to the height 
        divLayer.style.top = top

        // Set the div Left to the height 
        divLayer.style.left = left;
    }
    function SetHeightWidth(divLayer)
    {
        // Set the dialogbox width
        divLayer.style.width = divWidth + 'px';
        // Set the dialogbox Height
        divLayer.style.height = divHeight + 'px'
    }
    function SetText(txtButton1,txtButton2)
    {
            // Set display text for the two buttons
            if(txtButton1 == null)
            document.getElementById('btnConfOK').innerText = txtFirstButton;
            else
            document.getElementById('btnConfOK').innerText = txtButton1;

                            // Set display text for the two buttons
            if(txtButton2 == null)
            document.getElementById('btnConfCancel').innerText = txtSecondButton;
            else
            document.getElementById('btnConfCancel').innerText = txtButton2;

    }
    function SetDefaultButton(defaultButton)
    {
            // Set the focus on the Cancel button
            document.getElementById(defaultButton).focus();
    }
```

Just Noticed that it goes upto this function

```
function SetText(txtButton1,txtButton2)
    {
            alert("2");
            // Set display text for the two buttons
```

then it get lost, its trying to get value from txtButton1 which could mean, the Div tags in my ASPX page didn't got rendered properly :(

```
                if(txtButton1 == null)
            document.getElementById('btnConfOK').innerText = txtFirstButton;
            else
            document.getElementById('btnConfOK').innerText = txtButton1;

            alert("3");
```

****EDIT** **If i remove SetText function, it does display but then it doesn't triggers my "OnClick" method and just refreshes the page****

```
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CssClass="gradientbutton"
    OnClick="btDelete_Click" OnClientClick="ShowMessage();this.disabled=true;this.value='Wait...';"
    Text="Delete" UseSubmitBehavior="False" Width="200px"  />
```

**Just realized getting error on pages even tho its displaying the confirmation box**

Says findElementbyid(..) is null or not an object

Comment: Look in the console of your browser, you'll see what's wrong with that code!

Comment: its VPC Windows server 2003 with IE 6 , which doesn't have developer tool neither it does let me install a new browser :/

Answer (score 1):

I think this

```
document.getElementById('btnConfOK')
```

Should use the ClientID rather than the actual ID as it is a .NET control the ID will get rewritten. So it should be

```
document.getElementById('<%=btnConfOK.ClientID%>')
```

Comment: Cheers but nope, didn't made any difference at all.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe somewhy, the src is being added without a '/' to the url...

Change this line:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript" src="CustomDialog.js"></script>
```

To:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript" src="./CustomDialog.js"></script>
```

If this doesn't work its either problem with the code, or you have placed it in another location 0_0

Comment: AS its going into the Script code now, so I assume this isn't the case here, its just not rendering the Div elements properly or something wrong with tutorial i guess